# Is it true that $(R\times S)[G]\cong R[G]\times S[G]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, noncommutative-algebra, group-rings

I know for two groups $G, H$ (not necessarily finite) we have $R[G\times H]\cong (R[G])[H]$, but I was wondering if we had a similar statement for rings $R,\,S$. In other words, if $R,\,S$ are two (possibly noncommutative rings), is it true that $(R\times S)[G]\cong R[G]\times S[G]$?

Comment: is it true if we just take $R=S=1$ ?

Comment: Did you try to write down some maps between them?

Comment: @seeker Do you mean the zero ring? If so, then yes, since $0[G]=0$.

Comment: @EspenNielsen :- ya i am sorry...i misinterpreted it.

Comment: What do you mean by $R[G]$ if $R$ is noncommutative?

Comment: Dear @QiaochuYuan Do you have a definition of the group ring in mind that needs commutativity? The standard definition via formal sums doesn't need to make mention of commutativity of $R$... I don't see how the functional definition does either... Regards

Comment: @rschwieb: the point is that there are two variants of the definition: one where the elements of $R$ are required to commute with the elements of $G$, and one where they aren't. Said another way: suppose $r_1 g_1$ and $r_2 g_2$ are two elements of the group algebra. What do you think their product is? Is it $(r_1 r_2) g_1 g_2$? If so, you're requiring that elements of $G$ and elements of $R$ commute.

Comment: A related question is: what do you think an $R$-algebra is? Is it an algebra $S$ equipped with a morphism $R \to S$? Or is it an algebra $S$ equipped with a morphism $R \to Z(S)$ (which is the notion that specializes to the usual notion when $R$ is commutative)? This is relevant if you want to define $R[G]$ as the left adjoint of a forgetful functor.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for clarifying where your concern is. Having read a great deal of literature under my belt about group rings, I can say without much doubt the second variant you speak of is vanishingly small. Where have you seen it?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I can see why you'd associate old discussion about why R-algebras "need" R to be commutative, but it isn't really that relevant here. That too is another case of rare usage not really worth mentioning when the standard interpretation is likely

Comment: @rschwieb: I wasn't just being pedantic; I don't actually know which one is the standard one, which is why I was asking.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan oh OK! I get where you're coming from then :) regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $T=R\times S$. Let $e=(1_R,0)1_G$ and $f=(0,1_S)1_G$ so that $(e+f)\cdot 1_G=1_{T[G]}$ .

Then $e$ and $f$ are central idempotents and $eT[G]=R[G]$, $fT[G]=S[G]$ and $T[G]$ is the direct product of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Since $R[G]$, is defined by the adjuction $Hom_{R-alg}(R[G], R')=Hom_{Grp}(G, R'^*)$. In particular the equality chain $$Hom_{R\oplus S-alg}((R\oplus S)[G], R')=Hom_{Grp}(G, R'^*)=Hom_{Grp}(G, R'^*)\oplus Hom_{Grp}(G, R'^*)=Hom_{R-alg}(R[G], R')\oplus Hom_{S-alg}(S[G], R')=Hom_{R\oplus S-alg}((R[G]\oplus S[G], R')$$ Thus $R[G]\oplus S[G]=(R\oplus S)[G]$!

Comment: I'm not fluent in such computations, so I ask a naive question or two now.  Is the coproduct of G with itself really necessary? Perhaps I overlooked something in my solution, but maybe it hasn't been long enough to realize why.

Comment: That coproduct looks wrong to me. For example, if $R = S$ is a field $k$ and $G$ is finite, then the LHS is finite-dimensional over $k but the RHS usually won't be.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yeap, you guys are right.